# "/bin/bash" command not found in self executable JAR

Tags: java, bash, jar

I have written the following code in my file.

```
String[] strg = new String[]{"/bin/bash","-c","ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams /Users/pftadmin/Desktop/PFTDEMO_Mp4_24.MP4"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strg);
```

I have exported it as a self executable JAR. When I am running the JAR from terminal using  `java -jar myJar.jar`, It runs fine with no error.

But when I am directly executing it by double click, it is showing below error.

> can not run program "/bin/bash" : error=2, No such file or directory

Please help me.

Comment: In your code you have forward slashes, and in the error you have backslashes. Did you copy & paste both?

Comment: What does "directly executing it by double click" mean?

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Both are forward slashes. I have edited please check.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström "directly executing it by double click" means executing the JAR by double clicking on it as it is an executable JAR.

Comment: I could guess that, my question referred to _where_ do you do the double clicking? In an IDE? In some file explorer?

Comment: @hammerfest the jar is in the desktop of a mac machine.

and I am clicking on the jar. It is not an IDE simple JAR file.

Comment: Ok I see. I do not have MAC desktop available, but I assume it does not behave as a unix shell, so /bin/bash is not an interpretable command from there

Comment: But @hammerfest when I am running the same JAR using terminal windows, it is giving me correct output.

java -jar MyRunOs.jar

Comment: Do you get error in console? Then post full error text.

Comment: dear @talex below is the exact error I got.

**can not run program "\bin\bash" : error=2, No such file or directory**

Comment: It is because MAC terminal is a unix shell, so /bin/bash is an interpretable command there. Your program seems to be otherwise OK, it depends on _which environment_ do you try to execute it, because /bin/bash is not an interpretable command in every environment. If you e.g. try to execute it in Windows, where you do not have /bin/bash, then it will probably also fail the same way

Comment: @hammerfest I got it now as I am new to OSX and linux OS. Cant we run such kind of commands from other than terminal

Comment: I’m a little mystified by why you’re using bash at all.  Isn’t `ffprobe` an executable program?

Comment: @SAnilKumarDora: You said it was forward slashes, but your "exact error" contains backslashes. Which is it now?

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström It is backward slashes. Sorry I am always little confused between these twos.

Comment: Then there is your problem. It should be forward slashes.

Comment: I updated your post with the exact error message you quoted.